# Efficient way to store different data types

Tags: java, linked-list

This is more of a conceptual question about how to most efficiently approach this issue, I'm utilizing LinkedLists created in a form I recently learned in class. I'll paste in both the node class I created as well as the LinkedList class itself. As I have the code set up now, I can only create lists with a single data type, in this instance being BufferedImages, but I want to be able to create one LinkedList for a BufferedImage and another for an int. Is there a better way to do this than making separate Node and LinkedList classes for each data type or overloading each class?

I want to be able to efficiently have two LinkedList objects storing different data types

```
//Node class:
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Node {
    private BufferedImage data;
    private Node link;

    public Node getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(Node link){
        this.link = link;
    }

    public BufferedImage getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(BufferedImage data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

//LinkedList class:
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class LinkedList {

    private Node root;
    public Node getRoot(){
        return root;
    }

    public void add(BufferedImage data) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node();
            root.setData(data);
        } else {
            Node tmp = root;
            while (tmp.getLink() != null) {
                tmp = tmp.getLink();
            }
            Node n = new Node();
            n.setData(data);
            tmp.setLink(n);
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        Node tmp = root;
        while (tmp != null) {
            count++;
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public BufferedImage get(int pos) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index " + pos + " is out of bounds.");
        }

        Node tmp = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        return tmp.getData();
    }

    public void set(int pos, BufferedImage data) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index " + pos + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        Node tmp = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        tmp.setData(data);
    }

    //DELETES LAST DATA
    public void delete(){
        if(root != null){
            Node tmp = root;
            for(int i=0; i < size()-2; i++){
                tmp = tmp.getLink();
            }
            tmp.setLink(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at "Java Generics": https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Comment: You won't be able to use generics to create a linked list of `int`. You could, however, create a linked list of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) using generics. You can use [Autoboxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) of primitives.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Once Valhalla gets here, that will finally change. I'm hoping we can reach that point in the next 3-4 years.

Comment: @Mauricio this link has opened an entire concept I did not know existed lol. Thank you

Comment: @d1zyz Java is a powerful language. Keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I find the baeldung article nod sufficient enough for beginners, I quickly re-wrote your code to support generics.

### Step 1: Make the inner workings generic, in this case your Node class:

In simple terms, instead of giving Node a fixed content like `BufferedImage`, we introduce our own type parameter. Usually that is simply called `<T>`, but here I go with `<MyGenericType>` to show that it can be handled like any other type.

The little downside is that we have to explicitly type `Node<MyGenericType>` wherever we use it, so this makes the code a bit longer.

```
package stackoverflow.linkedlist;

public class Node<MyGenericType> {
    private MyGenericType       data;
    private Node<MyGenericType> link;

    public Node<MyGenericType> getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(final Node<MyGenericType> link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public MyGenericType getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(final MyGenericType data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

### Step 2: Make the main class generic, your LinkedList:

Same here, introduce generics

```
package stackoverflow.linkedlist;

public class LinkedList<MyGenericType> {

    private Node<MyGenericType> root;
    public Node<MyGenericType> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void add(final MyGenericType data) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node<>();
            root.setData(data);
        } else {
            Node<MyGenericType> tmp = root;
            while (tmp.getLink() != null) {
                tmp = tmp.getLink();
            }
            final Node<MyGenericType> n = new Node<>();
            n.setData(data);
            tmp.setLink(n);
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        Node<MyGenericType> tmp = root;
        while (tmp != null) {
            count++;
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public MyGenericType get(final int pos) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index " + pos + " is out of bounds.");
        }

        Node<MyGenericType> tmp = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        return tmp.getData();
    }

    public void set(final int pos, final MyGenericType data) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index " + pos + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        Node<MyGenericType> tmp = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        tmp.setData(data);
    }

    //DELETES LAST DATA
    public void delete() {
        if (root != null) {
            Node<MyGenericType> tmp = root;
            for (int i = 0; i < size() - 2; i++) {
                tmp = tmp.getLink();
            }
            tmp.setLink(null);
        }
    }

}
```

### Step 3: Showcase some examples

Here I show you how to use the list. As you can see, we now have to define/introduce the 'concept' (aka Type) of BufferedImage from the outside, when we tell our list what type it should handle: `LinkedList<BufferedImage> imageList = new LinkedList<>();`

```
package stackoverflow.linkedlist;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class Usage {



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final LinkedList<BufferedImage> imageList = new LinkedList<>();
        final BufferedImage bi1 = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final BufferedImage bi2 = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        imageList.add(bi1);
        imageList.add(bi2);
        System.out.println("Size of image list is now: " + imageList.size());



        final LinkedList<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<>();
        intList.add(Integer.valueOf(667));
        intList.add(Integer.valueOf(668));
        intList.add(Integer.valueOf(669));
        System.out.println("Size of Integer is now: " + intList.size());



        final LinkedList<DemoCombo> mixedList = new LinkedList<>();
        mixedList.add(new DemoCombo(bi1, 667));
        mixedList.add(new DemoCombo(bi2, 668));
        System.out.println("Size of mixed list is now: " + mixedList.size());
    }



    static private class DemoCombo {
        public final BufferedImage  image;
        public final int            value;
        public DemoCombo(final BufferedImage pImage, final int pValue) {
            image = pImage;
            value = pValue;
        }
    }



}
```

I also included the DemoCombo class, because I was unsure why you wanted to have a list of BufferedImage and one of int.
Normally, if you have data that is related, like BufferedImage has a direct relation to the int, you should not have 2 different lists to store them in. In this case, it's a lot better to write a simple wrapper class, DemoCombo, so all data that belongs to each other is always together, and you do not have the pitfalls of having to manage 2 lists independently.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I can only create lists with a single data type, in this instance being BufferedImages, but I want to be able to create one LinkedList for a BufferedImage and another for an int. Is there a better way to do this than making separate Node and LinkedList classes for each data type or overloading each class? ..."*

Yes, you can use a *generic type*.

*[Lesson: Generics (Updated) (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)*.

```java
LinkedList<BufferedImage> a = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<Integer> b = new LinkedList<>();
```

```java
//Node class:
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> link;

    public Node<T> getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(Node<T> link){
        this.link = link;
    }

    public T getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

```java
//LinkedList class:
public class LinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> root;
    public Node<T> getRoot(){
        return root;
    }

    public void add(T data) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node<T>();
            root.setData(data);
        } else {
            Node<T> tmp = root;
            while (tmp.getLink() != null) {
                tmp = tmp.getLink();
            }
            Node<T> n = new Node<T>();
            n.setData(data);
            tmp.setLink(n);
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        Node<T> tmp = root;
        while (tmp != null) {
            count++;
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public T get(int pos) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index " + pos + " is out of bounds.");
        }

        Node<T> tmp = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        return tmp.getData();
    }

    public void set(int pos, T data) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The index " + pos + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        Node<T> tmp = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
        }
        tmp.setData(data);
    }

    //DELETES LAST DATA
    public void delete(){
        if(root != null){
            Node<T> tmp = root;
            for(int i=0; i < size()-2; i++){
                tmp = tmp.getLink();
            }
            tmp.setLink(null);
        }
    }

}
```